# Purging & Removing Part of URL

Tags: php, smarty, vine

I am creating a vine video sharing website.

I am having some issues. my og:image:secure_url won't pick up right because the url is getting displayed like this..

```
https://v.cdn.vine.co/v/thumbs/2013/04/30/5D309EAF-962F-41E1-8F22-41E4AA50FFB7-967-00000195162F03BD_1.0.7.mp4.jpg?versionId=JQ9YuwCeBry1sGZpZU40Z3wc_VF_PMb1
```

So facebook is giving me this error when bebugging..

```
   Object at URL 'http://vinesandstuff.com/' of type 'article' is invalid because the given value '' for property 'og:image:secure_url' could not be parsed as type 'url'.
```

How it's setup in the backend..

the og:image:secure_url setup, Note the script uses Smarty code.

```
<meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="{php} echo vine_pic($this->_tpl_vars['p']['youtube_key']);{/php}" />
```

and the script that grabs og:image from twitter..

```
function vine_pic( $id )
{

$vine = file_get_contents("http://vine.co/v/{$id}");
                                        preg_match('/property="og:image" content="(.*?)"/', $vine, $matches);

return ($matches[1]) ? $matches[1] : false;

}
```

**What I need help with**

Is removing this end part of the url `?versionId=JQ9YuwCeBry1sGZpZU40Z3wc_VF_PMb1`

I looked into other stackoverflow questions but I don't quite understand how it should be setup as in syntax. Could someone help me? Much is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use `parse_url` and `http_build_query` to tear that URL apart and put it back together without the versionID

I've never used smarty tags, so I'm not sure about that part. In php I'd do something like this: (untested)

```
$pic_link=vine_pic($this->_tpl_vars['p']['youtube_key']);
$parsed=parse_url($pic_link);
$pic_vars=parse_str($parsed['query']);
unset($pic_vars['$parsed']);
$new_query=http_build_query($pic_vars);
$new_pic_link=$parsed['scheme'].$parsed['host'].$parsed['path']'?'.$new_query;
//if the above is missing a slash, change the dot to .'/'.
?>
<meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="<?php echo $new_pic_link; ?>">
```

Comment: hmm But how should I setup the syntax tho? I've only a month into php and learning alot time by time so you'll have to excuse me.. I tried this aswell but I have no idea what part of my backend script should go where.. `$link = substr($linkraw, 0, strrpos($linkraw, "."))`

Comment: Hello TecBrat, I tried with your code, much less like `<?php ?>` it's called as `{php}{/php}` however I did try your update and `content=` outputted with a `?`